# Installing Adapta theme

Tags: 16.04, themes

After following Github installation with Ubuntu terminal it come to stop
 Terminal:

```
luis@luis-desktop:~$ cd /home/luis/.themes/adapta-gtk-theme-master
luis@luis-desktop:~/.themes/adapta-gtk-theme-master$ ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: 11: ./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found
luis@luis-desktop:~/.themes/adapta-gtk-theme-master$
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to install autoreconf. Run `sudo apt install autoreconf`.

Comment: Installing of autoreconf failed.
 
luis@luis-desktop:~$ sudo apt install autoreconf
[sudo] password for luis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package autoreconf
luis@luis-desktop:~$

Comment: I mistyped the package name. It's **`autoconf`**.